# Using the addition principle of combinatorics, find the number of non-negative integer solutions to $2x + 3y \leq 7$

Tags: combinatorics

Using the addition principle of combinatorics, find the number of non-negative integer solutions to $2x + 3y \leq 7$. This problem is found in the book *How to Count* by Beeler which contains no solutions, so I have no way of verifying the correct solution.

Comment: show us your try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Add the number of integer solutions of the equation  $2x+3y=n$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,7.$

Comment: We want the number of nonnegative integer solutions, so $n$ can be equal to $0$ as well.

Comment: yes, if $0$ is an integer